# iOS - Upgrade Firebase products version on an Objective-C project

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, cocoapods

I have an old Objective-C project that contains `Firebase/Core` and `Firebase/Messaging`. I have to upgrade all those librairies and add other `Firebase` products. In the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#objective-c_1) there is no mention of the versions only the libraries name like this `pod 'Firebase/Messaging'`. Even if I try a `pod install` remove the libraries names from the `PodFile` make `pod install` to remove them, then re-add them in the `PodFile` and make `pod install` I find in the `PodFile.lock` that the installed versions are not the last ones.

How is it possible to upgrade Firebase libraries installed by `CocoaPods` in order to get the last versions on an Objective-C project ?

The min `iOS` deployement target is: `8.0`

Answer (score 0):

Use `pod update` instead of `pod install` to get the latest versions. If you're still not getting latest versions, examine the `Podfile.lock` file to see what dependencies restrict the version.

Comment: I tried pod update but the version has not changed.  Can you please clarify this please "see what dependencies restrict the version"? And what if I delete the PodFile.lock ?

Comment: The Podfile.lock contents show why CocoaPods chooses the version it does. Presumably there is a requirement that is preventing the latest version from being installed.